# Accessing private members in a class

Tags: c++, class, private-members

I need to access an object from a DLL, do some manipulations to the object and feed the object to another function. The trouble is the fields I need to change are private.

I don't want to change the private modifier for the fields in the original class because the class was written a long time ago and is used in many places. However, the place where I am manipulating the class I need most of the fields without protection (it is a hack). What is the best way to do it?

Note: I am not allowed to change the original class

Comment: What do you mean by "it is a hack?" The way you're describing this makes it seem like you're approaching this completely incorrectly if you want to modify private fields externally.

Comment: To quote [Burt Bacharach and Carole Bayer Sager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That's_What_Friends_Are_For): [That's What `friend`s Are For](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html).

Comment: @templatetypedef-as per the original design the fields should not be accessed, which is true even now. But we have a new dll now and passing the object to the dll in the current format needs a lot of changes in the DLL code which we want to avoid.

Comment: @confusedcoder: if you cannot modify the class, this cannot be (safely/portably) done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see the original class you can make a mock class with the same bit pattern and cast the original object to the mock class object

Example below

Original class

```
class ClassWithHiddenVariables
{
private:
    int a;
    double m;

};
```

Mock class

```
 class ExposeAnotherClass
    {
    public:
        int a_exposed;
        double m_exposed;
    };
```

When you want to see members of the ClassWithHiddenVariables object, use reinterpret_cast to cast to ExposeAnotherClass

```
 ClassWithHiddenVariables obj;
    obj.SetVariables(10, 20.02);    
    ExposeAnotherClass *ptrExposedClass;
    ptrExposedClass = reinterpret_cast<ExposeAnotherClass*>(&obj);  
    cout<<ptrExposedClass->a_exposed<<"\n"<<ptrExposedClass->m_exposed;
```

Comment: is the bit pattern guaranteed to be same for both the classes

Comment: provided you use the same compiler and settings I think yes. You can do some checks if you have any public variables in the class-just check the public members of the original object are equal to corresponding mock object members.

Answer (score 3):

What is compiled in the DLL is not really important in this case, what matters is the **header file** you include. I suggest you change the header file of the class you're interested in so that the variables you need are `public`.

Member access is checked by compiler and not by the linker, so all that matters is how the class is declared. This does *not* require you to recompile the DLL or change the implementation of the class, but to just modify the header file (or a copy of the header file).

Comment: Given that the OP wants a hack and is prepared to deal with the days or weeks of debugging it will inevitably cause, this seems like the best hack.

Comment: +1 , I like it, but one concern is the amount of confusion this will cause to anybody who will look into the code in the future

Comment: @confusedcoder, hacks are hacks... If you put a big fat comment next to your change in the class it should help future maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it: Write Getter / Setter functions

Comment: That's not really hiding anything. That's just exposing them through other means.

Comment: @jisaak-but I am not allowed to change the original class.

Comment: @jisaak: And Yet it leaves a big wide window for everyone to access them, Since the `public` methods will be accessible to every user of the class.This infact breaks Encapsulation.

Comment: Getters and setters are just one tiny step better than public members. A real interface should almost always be preferred.

Comment: @jisaak: **No**, if the data is fully accessible through those getters/setters, then the data is *in no way* "hidden". It's completely visible.

Comment: @jisaak: I agree with the other people. I want the protection intact except the place I am doing the hack. Get/Set are nowhere related to the problem I need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The "Forger" hack from **Exceptional C++ Style, Item 15** will work. Although, it is illegal as it violates the One Definition Rule so I'd advise against doing this in production code.

From page 106

```
// Example 15-1: Lies and Forgery
//
class X {
    // instead of including x.h, manually (and illegally) duplicates X's
    // definition, and adds a line such as:
    friend ::Hijack( X& );
};

void Hijack( X& x ) {
    x.private_ = 2;
}
```

Note how class X's private member "private_" is accessible in Hijack.